# Contact form in a lightbox?

Tags: forms, lightbox

Hi i have an icon for contact now, when you click on it it's just a simple mailto:

But i want to have it open a lightbox window with a simple 3 field contact form in it. 
What is the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Any hint what technology you're using? HTML/CSS? ..

Comment: Yes just simple HTML/CSS splash page, with a contact icon which i want to open in a lightbox with a contact form.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I used FancyBox with a PHP contact form.